# Build classes to retrieve data from SQL

Tags: python, sql

I have the following exercise:

"You have a SQL table table with 4 columns (id, website, date_of_upload, rating). The task is to build a different classes that enable a query that can filter the table with any combination of this possibilities:

a) id: >, <, =, IN, NOTIN

b) website: =

c) date_of_upload: >, <, =

d) rating: >, <, =" "

I am not sure how to approach this task.

I can create a class as follow:

`class MyClass:

```
def __init__(self, database_name):
    db = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
    self.cursor = db.cursor()

def query_fetch_all(self, sql):
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
    return self.cursor.fetchall()`
```

And I wrote some class methods to retrieve the database entities

BUT

I am not understating why in the exercise is said to use "classes" (plural).
Can you give me an example where I use multiple classes to solve this issue?

I have really no clue, I thought one class with methods were enough.

In addition the task should that 30 minutes, while with my way, it is taking hours to write code to validate all the user input.

Comment: this question has the feel of `filters.py` from Flask-Restless (Extra to Flask+SQLAlchemy) [link here](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/blob/master/flask_restless/search/filters.py). I'm guessing question wants you to elevate the filters to their own class and have some fuctionality to combine filters. 30 minutes for this is laughable unless you've been given previous example on which to base this. Are you allowed to use SQLAlchemy / have you encountered this before?

Comment: No, it is in pure python sadly

Comment: if you're using one class how are you handling the requirement to allow any combination of the filters?

Comment: That is a good point, I basically created more functions/methods. Thus, I think I am not doing it properly because I repeat code